# Auto change the height of arrow according to content height (Liquid slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

[image]
[image]

From the screenshots, you can see the arrows are not auto adjust according to the content height when I press to next slide.

I want the dynamic height for arrow, to be displayed in the middle of the content.

I refer the code from Liquid Slider, you can check [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Content-slider-with-HTML5-Liquid%20Slider/) or see my issue below. Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

```js
$('#slider-id').liquidSlider({
  hoverArrows: false,
 dynamicArrows: true,
});
```

```css
[class$="-arrow"] {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(../images/arrow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 40% !important;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Content-slider-with-HTML5-Liquid%20Slider/js/jquery.liquid-slider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Content-slider-with-HTML5-Liquid%20Slider/css/liquid-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="liquid-slider"  id="slider-id">
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 2</h2>
    <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
  </div>          
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 3</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 4</h2>
    <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By overiding the arows css , setting the margin-top to 0 and top to 50% as follow :

```
[class$="-arrow"] {
    ....
    top:50%;
    margin-top:0 !important;
    ...
}
```

See below snippet :

```js
$('#slider-id').liquidSlider({
  hoverArrows: false,
 dynamicArrows: true,
});
```

```css
[class$="-arrow"] {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(../images/arrow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:0 !important;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Content-slider-with-HTML5-Liquid%20Slider/js/jquery.liquid-slider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Content-slider-with-HTML5-Liquid%20Slider/css/liquid-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="liquid-slider"  id="slider-id">
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 2</h2>
    <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
  </div>          
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 3</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 4</h2>
    <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad You're Welcome @Eelyn

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is helpful to you. Here i removed margin from top and added position to slider arrows.

```js
$('#slider-id').liquidSlider({
  hoverArrows: false,
 dynamicArrows: true,
});
```

```css
[class$="-arrow"] {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(../images/arrow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 0;
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
}

.liquid-slider-wrapper .liquid-nav-left-arrow, .liquid-slider-wrapper .liquid-nav-right-arrow {
margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Content-slider-with-HTML5-Liquid%20Slider/js/jquery.liquid-slider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Content-slider-with-HTML5-Liquid%20Slider/css/liquid-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="liquid-slider"  id="slider-id">
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 2</h2>
    <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
  </div>          
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 3</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 4</h2>
    <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```